# OS VectorMap Local not styling RailCLine and RoadCLine

Tags: qgis-3, style, ordnance-survey

I am running QGIS 3.14.1 (64 bit version) on a Windows 10 PC. I have downloaded two 5km tiles of the VectorMap Local (3 July version) in Geopackage format. My Parish Council holds the relevant OS Licence. I have downloaded the relevant styles from Github, in QML format. When I load them, Text, Line and Area seem to work but RailCLine and RoadCLine do not - see this screengrab:
[image: Neville's Cross on QGIS: 1:5000]
The two A roads should be coloured and also the East Coast main railway line should be shown. When I look at the symbology and the symbol levels the colours are there as the various fills.

Clearly I am missing something, but what?

I have looked at the other posts here, but most of them are nearly seven years old and relate to different levels of QGIS and map. There is one fairly recent question but that does not seem to have been resolved.

---

I've looked at the references but they don't help me (though I may be overlooking something, of course.) There are differences in that I am using QGIS 3.14 (not 2) and the map is VectorMap Local not District. This may or may not be significant. I have looked at the Layer properties, clicked to edit the rule (but not actually changed it) then clicked Test. It's finding the features, just not displaying them properly:

Please [image: Layer properties]

Comment: have a look at the style panel for those layers and see if you can see an issue - most likely is a mismatch in capitalization of attributes

Comment: related CLASSIFICATION gets truncated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232328/styling-os-maps-in-qgis-2-18-with-qml

Comment: Thanks for those comments. I have added further information to my original post, but I'm no further forward...

Answer (score 5):

there seems to have been an issue with some of the attribute headers being capitals when they should be lower case. The stylesheets have been amended now for both rail and road in backdrop and full colour.
https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-Local-stylesheets/tree/master/Geopackage%20stylesheets/QGIS%20Stylesheets%20(QML)

Comment: Thank you Paul, that works perfectly.